# Genereting 'n' html inputs based on database variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, input

My intention is to create a form in HTML where the user could register some quality features of a product. The number of features to be registered varies according to the model, this info is registered on a table in SQL.

So far I manage to generate the inputs, but it is very fast, the user cannot fill all the inputs.

````
## query to get the product information from database ## 

$query_list = "SELECT * FROM data_products";
$result_list = mysqli_query($conn, $query_list);

## get the number of rows
$query_data_rows = mysqli_query($conn, $query_list);
$data_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query_data_rows);
?>

## here is the first form, where the user selects the product model, 
## therefore it should query the number of raws (n) registered on the table

<div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="getdata()">
        <select name="select1">
            <option value=" "> </option>
            <?php
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_list)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['customer_Id'] . "'>" . $row['customer_Id'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go"/>
    </form>
</div>

## here my intention is to return the (n) number of input fields
## it correctly displays the number of input fields, but it is very fast
## I am missing something here

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['select1'])){ ?>
<form id="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php       
}
?>

## I am almost zero skilled on Javascript, 
## but browsing on the world web wide and reading the documentation of the language 
## I got the code below.  

<script>    
    function getdata() {
        var no = <?php echo $data_rows['number'] ;?>;
        for(var i=0;i<no;i++) {
            var textfield = document.createElement("input");
            textfield.type = "text";
            textfield.value = "";
            textfield.name = i+1 + "a"
            textfield.placeholder = i+1
            document.getElementById('form').appendChild(textfield);
        }
    }
</script> ```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "it is very fast"?

Comment: it just flashes on the screen and disappears.

Comment: Of course, because your form _submits_, and your JavaScript submit handler does not _prevent_ this default action.

Comment: But there’s more stuff here that does not make sense, like `var no = <?php echo $data_rows['number'] ;?>`, here you appear to be outputting the value for the _first_ product record you read from the database all the time, there does not seem to be any limitation of this to any _selected_ product.

Comment: All in all, to me this reads like another case of missing basics, I think you should probably go and have a good, thorough read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming first of all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what actually happening is that when you are submitting the form `getdata()` function is called till the it get submitted, after submission is done the content called by function disappears, in order to avoid this use `return false` statement at the end of the function.

```
<div class="container">
<form action="" id="form_id" method="post" onsubmit="return getdata()">
    <select name="select1">
        <option value=" "> </option>
        <?php
            //accesing the database table
            $query_list = "SELECT * FROM `data_products`";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_list);
            //to get rows
            $data_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            echo $data_rows;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['srno'] . "'>" . $row['srno'] . "</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="go"/>
</form></div>
<?php 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
        echo '<form id="form" action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit">
        </form>';
    }
?>      

<script>    
    function getdata() {
        var no = <?php echo $data_rows;?>;
        for(var i=0;i<no;i++) {
            
            var btn = document.createElement("INPUT");
            btn.type = "text";
            btn.value = "";
            btn.name = i+1 + "a"
            btn.placeholder = i+1
            document.getElementById('form').appendChild(btn);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
</script>
```

This is working. Here I have made some changes in your code like replacing 'textfield' with 'btn', 'customerid' with 'srno' (for easy understanding) and avoid using php again and again.

Comment: Your post helped me in the way to find the solution. I meant I wanted the number of inputs based on the info registered for each product, I just had to do a slightly change and it worked fine.

Comment: the only little problem now is that the inputs are just appearing after clicking twice on the 'go' button.